# Installed Linux On A Dual Boot With Windows XP But Cant Load Linux on Startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-xp

I have a small 40gb hard drive which was running windows xp on its own with 9gb reserved for the recovery partition and 1gb empty (I assume for the swap partition).

Anyway I decided to overwrite Linux on the recovery partition.  I couldn't figure out how to make a swap partition for Linux but it installed suucessfully and asked to be restarted.

On reboot it goes straight to windows and there is no option to choose which operating system to boot.  When I go to disk management in windows it is finding 2 unknown partitions which are the 9gb and 1gb partitions.

Any ideas as how to boot into Linux?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Super Grub 2](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) to boot yours OS

Answer (score 0):

Normally when installing linux it installs grub (the most used one), which is a boot manager.  It's written in the Master Boot Record of you HDD.
Was grub or any boot manager installed with your linux ?
Which distribution of linux did you choose ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer I used Ubuntu 11.10. I installed from a pen drive, but I am not sure if the grub was installed.